# Renewing VLSTS French visa

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, france, long-stay-visas

I have a "Passport Talent" visa for France. The information written on the visa is:

- Valid for: France
- From: 11-12-22
- Until: 10-04-23
- Duration of stay: XXX
- Type of visa: D
- Number of entries: Mult
- Remarks: Pass. Talent; Chercheur; PT4 VLSTS; Valider en ligne

I am trying to extend my stay from 10 April to 30 April (I have new agree with my host university). When I start the online application form for renewal (here: https://administration-etrangers-en-france.interieur.gouv.fr/), it says:

> **You are holder of a VLS-TS as a « PASSEPORT TALENT ».**
>
> The online application procedure for this type of residence permit is
> currently unavailable. Please visit the website of the Prefecture of
> your residence for information on the steps to be taken.

Can someone how can I extend my stay? I have no idea what is the website of "Prefecture of my residence".

Comment: This question about a long-stay visa would be better placed on [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4):

> Can someone how can I extend my stay?

I am not really sure about that because there is very little information about that

> I have no idea what is the website of "Prefecture of my residence"

A *Préfecture* is an administrative representation of the state in your *département*.

Every *departement* in mainland France has one, you can check what *département* you are in by :

- Look at the address of where you are currently living
- Find the 5 digit zip-code (eg. `01000`)
- Take the first two digits, this is your *département* code (`01` here)
- Go on Google and search for `préfecture <département code>`, the first result should be a link ending in `.gouv.fr`, this is your Prefecture's website

NOTE : Paris itself is specific in the fact that it is a *Préfecture de Police* and not a *Préfecture*

> (I have new agree with my host university)

I'd **really** suggest you contact your university's foreign students office for guidance, they will very likely know better about your situation.